# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets"

Tags: ros, wstool

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using indigo in ubuntu14.04.2 following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying). I did like this:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/overlay_ws
$ cd ~/overlay_ws
$ mkdir -p ~/overlay_ws/src
$ cd ~/overlay_ws/src
$ wstool init
```

then added a ros package

```
$ wstool set ros_tutorials --git git://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials.git
$ wstool update
```

build it

```
$ source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
$ cd ~/overlay_ws/
$ catkin_make
```

error occured:

```
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at ros_tutorials/turtlesim/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

my questions is :
1 What's the relationship between ROS and the Qt5 ?

2 Should I install Qt5 in my PC ?
thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236324/could-not-find-a-package-configuration-file-provided-by-%22qt5widgets%22/) by [yongqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27003/yongqi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. It is used to build GUIs, as the one for turtlesim (but also the whole rqt series, including rviz)
2. Yes. You might be fine just issuing `rosdep install turtlesim`. Otherwise check out the qt related packages in package.xml and install them via `sudo apt-get install ...`

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yongqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27003/yongqi/) on 2016-06-07**:
thanks for replay. I have installed turtlesim and I can not find package.xml, I think it is created after catkin_create_pkg.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-06-08**:
try `sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev` then

**Comment by [yongqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27003/yongqi/) on 2016-06-08**:
thanks very much, `sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev` works for me